# Can I start two fragments in one NavHostFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I have a fragment screen with with two sections 1) image card and 2) tablayout with view pager which they are split into two XML files and two Fragment lifecycle java file. Also, I have one NAV host fragment in my activity and one NAV graph. Can I start the two XMLs at once in the NAV host fragment such that I can display the two XMLs, section 1) and 2), vertically.

**Remark:** I DON'T have room to add/create XML/NAVHostFragment to include the two XMLs. Anything in Java will work for me.

Anyone has any insight on how to do that under such situation?

Here is what I started:

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navhostfragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navgraph" />
</LinearLayout>
```

imagecard.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
     android:id="@+id/cardview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

viewpager.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Possible Solution is:

1. Create a Fragment `MainFragment` with a viewpager.
2. Set that fragment as Start destination in Navgraph.
3. Load `cardimage` and `tabLayout` in the `MainFragment`s viewpager
4. Set the Orientation of the Main Viewpager to vertical by calling `setOrientation()`

Comment: @Prathamesth Thanks for your solution. I gave a try on it and the result is the cardimage and tablayout are in two pages in the viewpager. Is there way to remove the paging?

Comment: I also try to google if I can use fragment in recyclerview.viewholder. Seems it is not a practice. The FragmentViewHolder is also special for Viewpager2.

Comment: @HowardLau didn't get your question. paging as in the loading state of the fragment?